# Google App Script: get values from range and set them to another range in different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I did spend some time to find solution for this, but in vain.

I am a beginner to google appScript.

I have list of values in sheet1(ASINs to review) from (B5:B60) and its dynamic(number of rows change due to query on the sheet). I am trying to pro-grammatically pull them and try to paste them in sheet2(app).

I am able to successfully pull the data, but unable to paste them in sheet2.

My code:

```
    function myFunction() {

  var asinsToReview = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ASINs to Review");
  var lr = asinsToReview.getLastRow();
  var title = asinsToReview.getRange(5, 2, lr).getValues();


  var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("app");
  var pasteRange = pasteSheet.getRange("A2:A").setValue(title);

}
```

Comment: You want to use `setValues` instead of `setValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 function myFunction() {

  var asinsToReview = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ASINs to Review");
  var lr = asinsToReview.getLastRow();
  var title = asinsToReview.getRange(5, 2, lr).getValues();


  var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("app");
  var pasteRange = pasteSheet.getRange(2,1,lr,1).setValues(title);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @cooper for your help. 

I have a quick question wrt the above initial question. The var "pasteRange" will paste the values that would look like:

Hello how are you
Hello how is your father doing
etc
etc

I want to achieve two things:
1. remove a standard word("Hello") from all lines;
2. now spilt the remaining words into separate columns, with delimiter "(space)".. my result should look like: col1:How col2:are col3:you. 

appreciate your help :)
cheers
Bala